# How do i append some value to an instance variable in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, instance-variables

Here's what I am trying to do in my home controller:

```
def view
    @product= Product.find(params[:id])
    rand_price = rand(202- @product.price.to_i) + @product.price.to_i
    old_price = rand_price + @product.price.to_i

    @product << old_price  #error line
end
```

I want to add one more value of `old_price` to my variable without adding a column for the same in the `Product` model. The error is:

```
undefined method `<<' for #<Product:0x7f1362cc5b88>
```

Comment: Not sure why anyone would give a -1 to this. It's a valid question to wanting good, clean, re factored code.

Answer (score 2):

Use serializers
In model:

```
class Product << ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :prices, Array

  ...
end
```

Column products.prices in database should be string.

And in controller

```
def update
  @product= Product.find(params[:id])
  rand_price = rand(202- @product.price.to_i) + @product.price.to_i
  new_price = rand_price + @product.price.to_i

  @product.prices << new_price
  @product.save!
end
```

And you may use it:

```
  @product.prices # => array of all prices.
  @product.prices.last # => current price
```

Answer (score 1):

You can say

```
class << @product
  attr_accessor :old_price
end
@product.old_price = old_price
```

which injects an attribute into the instance variable.

`<<` the way you are referring to it adds a value to an array, which is not what you're looking to do.

An alternative would be to add:

`attr_accessor :old_price`

to your `Product` model.  That would add `old_price` to all instances of `Product` without it being a field in the table.

Comment: thanks, but where do i put this class and after doing that can i still make @product, a product model object?

Comment: You can put this anywhere before where you want to access the `old_price` property.  It's not a separate class, it's modifying the class of `@old_price`.  I added an alternative to the answer that's simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Error, because @product is Product object not Array.

<< use with Array object

and Ruby has not permission to add property by this way (like Javascript).

You should declare an attr_accessor of 'old_price'